# How create a function for defining .pdf size

Tags: python, pdf, module, size

Let's take the case I should print the number of bytes taken by PDF files in the directory tree (".pdf" extensions). I wrote down the following code which seems to work but, I am not sure it returns what I am looking for.

```
import os
def find_pdf_size(files):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(os.path.getsize(top)) 
  
top = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Preludium/Preludium(2)/Articles/MM'
print(find_pdf_size(top))
```

Since this code returns always the same number, repeated for the number of files within the file folder, I suppose. Could you please let me know how to move out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
import os
def find_pdf_size(files):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(os.path.getsize(top)) 
  
top = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Preludium/Preludium(2)/Articles/MM'
print(find_pdf_size(top))
```

does report size of `top` which does not change so you get repeated value use `os.path.join` to get path to file you want to measure, that is do

```
import os
def find_pdf_size(files):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root,name))) 
  
top = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Preludium/Preludium(2)/Articles/MM'
print(find_pdf_size(top))
```

From [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) docs

> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a
> full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath,
> do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
import os


def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix="B"):
    for unit in ["", "Ki", "Mi", "Gi", "Ti", "Pi", "Ei", "Zi"]:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return f"{num:3.1f}{unit}{suffix}"
        num /= 1024.0
    return f"{num:.1f}Yi{suffix}"


def find_pdf_size(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(f"File name: {name} and its size: {sizeof_fmt(os.path.getsize(name))}")


path = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Preludium/Preludium(2)/Articles/MM'
print(find_pdf_size(path))
```

Or without format

```py
import os

def find_pdf_size(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(f"File name: {name} and its size: {(os.path.getsize(name))}")


path = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Preludium/Preludium(2)/Articles/MM'
print(find_pdf_size(path))
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a small mistake while passing argument in your function `get_size_of`. Update your code with the function below

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\HPvns\Desktop\cycle"
def print_size(path):
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".pdf"):
                print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name)))
```